# Timed/Periodical automatic uploads to DropBox?

Tags: storage, macros, dropbox, upload, cloud

I'm wondering if there are any tools/apps out that allow you to; select a specific set of files/folders -> select a specific time (every 3 hours for example) -> automatically upload/sync the selected folders/files with DropBox every 3 hours.

This would be great to have, or something similar enough to; as I always find I've got a lot of key files that I'd like uploaded to my cloud storage accounts (i.e. DropBox), but my schedule often throws me off and I don't end up doing it myself.

Any info on whether this exists would be great!

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to sync some folders with the dropbox folders on a schedule?  So as the dropbox folders aren't special, the general form of this question is: is there an application that can sync folders on a schedule?  If so, it has been asked and answered previously.

Comment: @Paul Link to the question?

Comment: Waiting for clarification - but a search for `sync windows` will provide lots of variations for windows, and obviously rsync for linux

Comment: TravelingTechGuy Windows 7 (x64), @Paul Yeah, that's exactly what I need thanks! Maybe you want to post up a link to the thread (I'm about to search for it myself), so that I can select it as the answer and pass credit to you?

Comment: This is closest I think [Which is the best application to Sync two folders?](http://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders)